# How do the chemical components of these spices prevent fungal growth?

Tags: molecular-biology

I am doing an EE on how spices affect fungal growth for the following spices - 
oregano,
garlic,
cinnamon,
cumin and turmeric. Its been hard to find any sites that say why or how they affect fungal growth, as far as I can tell I am pretty sure they affect the Krebs (TCA) cycle and inhibit the production of ATP. It would be great if someone could help me explain why :)

Comment: What is the reason for your assumption that the inhibit ATP production?

Comment: 1. What is EE? 2. Do you have any data/reference to say that these spices even have an effect on fungi? If you don't prove that first then the "how" makes no sense.

Comment: I have seen papers which talk about inhibiting ATP production, and that components of spice ( like curcuminoids and thymols etc ) can do that